# Try and catch not working JOptionPane(Java)

Tags: java, swing, try-catch, joptionpane

I have a JList and a string that is the JList's selection. If you click a JButton, It displays your JList selection. If you don't click a JList selection, It returns an error, So i used try catch, but it still returned an error.

here is my code, there are no errors in editor.:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String choice = chooser.getSelectedValue().toString();
    String companyname = name.getText();
    try{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"<html> Welcome to your new Company!<br><br>Company type: " + choice + "" + "<br>" + "Company Name: "  + companyname  + "" +"</html>"  );   
    }catch (Exception e1){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please fill in both inputs");
    }
}
```

And also the try works fine if there's no error, but the catch just doesn't work. I also tried to catch NullPointerException and if ,else if choose = null, but it still didn't work. Not even the option pane pops up with null in its place.

Answer (score 4):

Just where would expect an exception to occur?

```
try{
    String choice = chooser.getSelectedValue().toString();
    String companyname = name.getText();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"<html> Welcome to your new Company!<br><br>Company type: " + choice + "" + "<br>" + "Company Name: "  + companyname  + "" +"</html>"  );   
}catch (Exception e1){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please fill in both inputs");
}
```

*MIGHT* be a better solution, given the fact that `JList#getSelectedValue` will return `null` if nothing is selected...but then you would need to catch a `NullPointerException` or `Throwable` instead of `Exception`

**Updated with example**

Branching by exception is not a good way to design applications.  Exceptions should be used to trap unexpected states.  You would seem that you are expecting invalid results.

A better approach would be to actually inspect each of the values in turn and determine if they are valid.

```
    Object value = chooser.getSelectedValue();
    if (value != null && value instanceof String) {
        String choice = chooser.getSelectedValue().toString();
        String companyname = name.getText();
        if (companyname != null && companyname.trim().length() > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"<html> Welcome to your new Company!<br><br>Company type: " + choice + "" + "<br>" + "Company Name: "  + companyname  + "" +"</html>"  );   
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The company name is invalid, please provide one");
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your company type choice is invalid, please select one");
    }
```

Comment: You might add that he could just check for the `null` instead of catching the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @DaoWen Fingers don't type that fast :P

Comment: "..but then you would need to catch a NullPointerException or Throwable instead of Exception.." don't like it, catch `RuntimeException` if an Error happen i doubt you can do something.. also `companyname.trim.length > 0` `company.trim().isEmpty()` would be better

Comment: @nachokk I agree, hence the update.  The OP's code would never catch the `NullPointerException` as it is a `RuntimeException`/`Error`/`Throwable`, not an `Exception`, hence the comment.  Better still, if they are REALLY worried about it, they should try using an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` instead

Comment: @nachokk But it still bad practice to use exceptions as decision branches.

Comment: mm a `NullPointerException`  is a `Exception` if you catch Exception you catch NullPointerException :S

Comment: @nachokk Ah true, I always treat them differently, don't like catching `RuntimeExceptions` :P

Comment: is curious that the 2 answer say that catch exception don't catch nullpointer

Comment: More commonly, we shouldn't be trying to trap `Exception`, but trying to trap particular exceptions (like `NullPointerException`), but in this case, it's a bad idea, as they are expecting a possible `null` value.  I had, somewhere, in the back of my head the `NullPointerException` was an `Error`

Answer (score 1):

Im fairly sure `showMessageDialog()` doesn't throw any exceptions, if any probably just a null pointer. Maybe try an if-else.

EDIT Here is some code, this should work as a full replacement.
Code:

```
if(! choice == null){
    if(!companyname.equals("");){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "<html> Welcome to your new Company!<br><br>Company type: "+ choice + " " + "<br>" + "Company Name:"  + companyname  + "" +"</html>");
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please fill in the company name!");
    }
}else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Plaease fill in choice!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not guaranteed that the showing of the dialog will be done on the calling thread - if `showMessageDialog()` is invoked from a background thread, the UI will still be displayed on the event thread - the calling thread will just be blocked until it is closed.

If the UI does throw an exception, it will happen on a different thread and not propagate to your code (have a look at the source code to the AWT event queue to get an idea of the mechanics of this).